# Can't Render Composable iterating through List of Objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

`@Composable` invocations can only happen from the context of a `@Composable` function.

Can't render `Composable` iterating through list of Objects

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun verticalScroll() {

    var count by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        pageCount = {
            10
        }
    )

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    @Composable
    fun ScrollContent(innerPadding: PaddingValues) {

    }
    Column {
        VerticalPager(state = pagerState) { page -> //see function parameter lambda
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.volk),
                contentDescription = "Volkanovski",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
        }
        Row {
            listOfButtons.map {

                Button(onClick = {
                    count = it
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        // Call scroll to on pagerState
                        pagerState.scrollToPage(count)
                    }
                })
                {
                    Text(text = "$it")
                }

            }
        }


        /*
        * TopBar - dummy icons
        * Main Content - scrollable Grid
        * BottomBar - dummy icons
        * */

        @Composable
        fun CenterAlignedTopBarExample() {

            val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())

            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
                topBar = {
                    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                        title = {
                            Text(
                                "Centered Top App Bar",
                                maxLines = 1,
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                            )
                        },
                        navigationIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                    contentDescription = "Localized description"
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        actions = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                                    contentDescription = "Localized description"
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,

                        )


                }

            ) { innerPadding ->
                Column(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                    
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PostCard(imageId: Int, contentDescription: String) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = imageId),
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)
    )
}

data class Post(val imageId: Int, val contentDescription: String)

val listOfPosts: List<Post> = listOf(

    Post(R.drawable.volk, "Volk"),
    Post(R.drawable.flower, "flower"),
    Post(R.drawable.tiger, "tiger"),
    Post(R.drawable.lion, "lion"),
    Post(R.drawable.man, "man"),
    Post(R.drawable.beetle, "beetle"),
    Post(R.drawable.car, "car"),
    Post(R.drawable.bike, "bike"),


    )

@Composable
fun grid() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.FixedSize(3.dp) ) {
       listOfPosts.map { 
           PostCard(imageId = it.imageId, contentDescription = it.contentDescription ) //got error underline on PostCard
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through a list Of objects and use a `Composable` to render each object and then put them all in a `LazyVerticalGrid`.

Comment: Have you tried using [the `items()` function shown in the documentation `](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`items`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridScope).items(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) function of [`LazyVerticalGrid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)).

Also note that doing `GridCells.FixedSize(3.dp)` will result in the grid columns being only 3dp wide, so this is probably not what you want. Check out the [`GridCells`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/GridCells) documentation to find out what suits your needs.

See the example below:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2) ) {  // show two columns
   items(listOfPosts) { 
       PostCard(imageId = it.imageId, contentDescription = it.contentDescription )
   }
}
```